# Some thumbnail is coming in ie over an image

Tags: html, css, image, internet-explorer, thumbnails

I have this html table and in one of the columns there is a image for view. The image is showing correctly on ff and chrome but there is some thumbnail or some thing coming over the image in ie. Pls help me as I am blank .

I am attaching the two images.

**chrome & FF**
[image: chrome and ff]

**and this one is for ie.**

[image: ie]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually I have used the below HTML:

```
<div>
<img alt="view" style="background-image:'/sampleimg.png'" href=""/>
</div>
```

and this bauses problem on IE. So i have modifies the html to

```
<div style="background-image:'sampleimg.png'">
<img alt="view" href=""/>
</div>
```

and the problem is solved